# Is it possible to get a new code analysis for every feature in sonarqube?

Tags: sonarqube, sonarqube-web

On the dashboard there is a cool [block with new code analysis](https://i.stack.imgur.com/oZqNn.png). I'd like to see something like this for every feature. I hoped to solve this using [sonar-branch-community plugin](https://github.com/s-pw/sonar-branch-community), but it doesn't measure coverage of new code in short-lived branches. As for long-lived branches - I tried to make all the feature branches long-lived. There is an analysis of new code in this case, but it starts from first scan of this branch and there is no way to compare it to another long-lived branch (or is it?)

Is there a way to execute the new code analysis by features? May be it's possible to pass 2 scanning results to this widget to see the difference?

Comment: the question is, what are you trying to achieve with this values -> e.g. if you want to ensure code quality and using bitbucket, you might want to checkout sonar4stash, which will show you this information within your pull request (but does not necessarily use the new branch plugin)

Comment: @SimonSchrottner the main reason is to get test coverage of new code. Does sonar4stash show this info?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Newer versions of SonarQube support reporting of code coverage on branches and the introduction of new issues compared to the target long-lived branch.

The [SonarQube Community Branch Plugin](https://github.com/mc1arke/sonarqube-community-branch-plugin) supports the new branch scanning features introduced in SonarQube 7.2, although I don't believe SonarQube provides the charted/visual history of the branches, just the numeric values.